# smart way to create a master list (avoiding cross joins)

Tags: sql, netezza

I need to create a Table of date,product and inventory count only for the days inventory 0 , something like this

```
Date Product store Inv
Jan1  1       1      0
Feb4  1       1      0
```

From the inventory table that only has a record whenever inventory changes 
Like this

```
 Store Product start_date end_date Inv
 1      1      Jan 4      Jan10    5
 1      1      Jan10      jan 15   4
```

I know I can create a master table by cross joining all store,product and calendar days in a year and then join only with days where date falls between start and end date of the inventory table. Is there a better way than this ? Can cross join be avoided ? Thanks

Comment: I am using netezza

Comment: Please provide a sample set of desired input and output records- February is not mentioned in your input, and the two dates mentioned in your output seems ‘out of the blue’ ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(inventory) over (partition by product, store order by date) as prev_inventory
      from t
     ) t
where prev_inventory is null or prev_inventory <> inventory;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a table with dates (which can be handy to have around for a ton of reasons) then left join from the inventory table and use `BETWEEN` against your date columns.

Comment: could you elaborate your suggestion, please ?